# SVGs saved with Phantomjs appear different compared to how they render in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, d3.js, phantomjs, word-cloud

I've been using Jason Davies' `d3.layout.cloud.js` (https://github.com/jasondavies/d3-cloud) to generate word clouds. The cloud SVGs look great in Chrome but now I'm trying to use Phantomjs to save multiple word cloud SVGs and when I do this I get overlap of the words.  I'm new to all these tools so I wondered if anyone has experienced a similar problem? Does the canvas element in Phantomjs behave differently compared to web browsers like Chrome?

Comment: Have you tried setting the size of the "window" explicitly with phantomjs?

Comment: Hi @LarsKotthoff do you mean setting page.viewportSize? This is something I have played around with without success. I have realised that there is no problem if I am using a basic font like 'Times New Roman' but I'm trying to use Montserrat so I think that context.measureText is not working correctly for web fonts and the canvas element (I'm using Phantomjs v2.0). I'm going to post another question about this, will add link to this comment thread

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30759584/problems-measuring-width-of-web-fonts-in-phantomjs-v2-0